# Error "Cannot find module 'eslint-config-strict/es5'" when I try to create a commit

Tags: javascript, git, protractor, cucumber, chai

I'm trying to create commit but i'm getting this error

```
Cannot find module 'eslint-config-strict/es5'
```

I already add to my package.json the `"eslint-config-strict": "^8.5.0",` 
and I have the package in my `node_module` with the `es5` inside of the `eslint-config-strict` folder.

Is any one any idea why i'm getting this error?

Thanks.

Comment: try `npm install`. And if that damn package-lock.json file is around, delete it and `npm install` again.

Comment: Is already install that package, the problem is whenI try to commit, is displaying that cannot find that module

Answer (score 2):

I found a possible cause. - It's the node.js version mismatch.

I installed node_modules using node 10, but was trying to run eslint using node 8.

Comment: If anyone is coming here after having this issue using Firebase Functions, it's likely not the cause, as Node 10 is already the default.